# searching specefic word in shell script

Tags: shell

I have a problem.Please give me a solution.

I have to run a command as I given below, which will list all the files that contain the string given "abcde1234".

> find /path/to/dir/ * | xargs grep abcde1234

But here it will display the files which contain the string "abcde1234567" also.But I nee only files which contain the word "abcde1234". What modification shall I need in the command ??

Comment: You could try adding word boundaries  `grep '\<abcde1234\>'`

Answer (score 4):

When I need something like that, I use the `\<` and `\>` which mean word boundary. Like this:

`grep '\<abcde1234\>'`

```
The symbols \< and \> respectively match the empty string at the beginning and end of a word.
```

But that's me. The correct way might be to use the `-w` switch instead (which I tend to forget about):

```
-w, --word-regexp
          Select  only  those  lines  containing matches that form whole words.  The test is that the matching substring must either be at the beginning of the line, or preceded by a non-word constituent character.  Similarly, it
          must be either at the end of the line or followed by a non-word constituent character.  Word-constituent characters are letters, digits, and the underscore.
```

One more thing: instead of `find` + `xargs` you can use just `find` with `-exec`. Or actually just grep with `-r`:

```
grep -w -r abcde1234 /path/to/dir/
```

Comment: This helped.Thanky ou aragaer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ grep abcde1234 *
```

This will grep the string `abcde1234` in current directory, with the file name in which the string is.
Ex:

```
abc.log: abcde1234 found
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I got the answer for this.By attaching $ with word to be searched, it will display the files that contain only that word.

The command will be like this.

> find /path/to/dir/ * | xargs grep abcde1234$

Thanks.

Comment: It will only display lines _ending_ with this word since `$` means "end of line"

Comment: This will fail if `abcd1234` is _not_ the last word in a particular line. @aragaer has the right answer/ideas